# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

Below mentioned is the JSON string, resultString:

```
{
"imageMaps": [{
        "crc": "c2c4",
        "flags": "0",
        "length": "117384",
        "index": 1,
        "version": "1.1.90ea",
        "status": ""
    }, {
        "crc": "7601",
        "flags": "8",
        "length": "117592",
        "index": 2,
        "version": "1.1.90ed",
        "status": ""
    }],
    "complete": true,
    "nextBootImageVersion": "",
    "lastKnownGoodImageVersion": "1.1.90ed",
    "runningImageVersion": "1.1.90ed"
}
```

I want to get the same converted to the object of class A:

```
public class A {

    private boolean complete;

    private String message;

    private String lastKnownGoodImageVersion;

    private String nextBootImageVersion;

    private String runningImageVersion;

    private Map<String, B> imageMaps;

    private  List<B> images;

    private MacID macId;

}
```

I am trying to convert the json to object of class A using the code :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);    
A a = objectMapper.readValue(resultString, A.class);
```

Code for class B is:

```
public static class B {
    public String version;
    public int flags; 
    public int crc; 
    public long length; 
    public String index;
    public String status;
}
```

But getting the exception :

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY
>   token

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You declared property `imageMaps` as a `Map<String, B>` in your class, but in your JSON `imageMaps` is an array of B. The deserialization should work if you change `imageMaps` to `images` in your JSON.

Comment: I don't have a control on the json string. I can change the structure of the class though.

Comment: In that case try changing `private Map<String, B> imageMaps;` to `private List<B> imageMaps;`